# What version of the Central Limit Theorem is this?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

In lectures the following was written down on the board

> $$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_1+\dots + X_n}{\sqrt{n}}>X\right)$$

Obviously this is in an incomplete state, and I all I managed to catch was that this had something to do with the Central Limit Theorem.

I've been unable to match this with any of the versions of the theorem and would appreciate even a link to the version which this incomplete state refers to.

For the sake of context, this appeared during a discussion of the following scenario:

> Suppose you place the tip of your pen on a piece of paper. The ink will spread out from it onto the paper and over a long period of time, almost surely converge to a circle

I assume that this is because of the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: Might it have said "$>x$" rather than "$>X$"? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy If it helps, then yes, it could have been a lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem:** If $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are i.i.d. with expected value $0$ and variance $1$ then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr\left( \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{\sqrt n} > x \right) = 1 - \Phi(x)
$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative probability distribution function of the standard normal distribution, given by
$$
\Phi(x) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-u^2/2}\,du.
$$

Comment: In the sense of the context, what would this mean informally? I think I'm not understanding how $\Phi$ is supposed to be seen as since I've not met this properly before.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  What it means is that the probability distribution of $(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/\sqrt n$ approaches the standard normal distribution as the sample size $n$ grows.  The expression on the right, $1-\Phi(x)$, is the probability that a standard normal random variable exceeds $x$.  Normally $\Phi(x)$ is defined as the probability that a standard normal random variable is less than $x$. $\qquad$

Comment: This explanation helped greatly, thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. $\qquad$

Comment: I've more frequently seen it stated somewhat like this: $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr\left( \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{\sqrt n} < x \right) = \Phi(x). $$  That amounts to the same thing, but it's a somewhat simpler way of saying it. $\qquad$

Comment: Should this be a $\leq x$ or does it not matter since the $X_i$ are continuous random variables (as opposed to discrete)? It's been a while since I've done probability and this is from a class on stochastic processes.

Comment: @IrregularUser : It can be done either way since this is a continuous distribution. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the $X_i$ are i.i.d. with $\Bbb{E}(X_i) = 0$ and finite variance, $\sigma^2$, $$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right) \xrightarrow{dist} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)  \text{.}$$  (This is the [Lindeberg-Levy CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT).)  The thing on the left is your $\dfrac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$, so your expression is just talking about right tails of a normal distribution.

Comment: I sort of see the connection, but what does the probability have to do with anything? With $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = 0$, does this mean we want the probability to be zero?

Comment: I can't guess what the noun phrase you quote "has to do with anything" without knowing more about what thing it appeared near.  For $\Bbb{E}(X_i) = 0$, we are saying that the distribution from which the $X_i$ are drawn has already had its mean subtracted out (because sliding everything to the right or left is not interesting).

Comment: Just added context to the question!